# Instantiate player prefab using player data

Tags: unity, c#

When my scene loads, I want to add my prefab to it along with its components.

Here is what I mean:

1. scene loads
2. player gender is determined via playerprefs or playfab sdk
3. player prefab is loaded and displayed using said gender

The prefab would have a script components attached for the current data etc.

I might be approaching this wrong, but I want this to work with multiplayer in the future, so that's why I didn't just add the prefab directly to the hierarchy.

What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to GDSE - what have you tried so far, and where are you getting stuck with it? Is your specific problem about instantiating prefabs, modifying them after instantiation, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use DontDestroyOnLoad for your player ? Maybe you could use an external script that assign what you want in your player script depending of what you want.
Ex:

```
GameObject player;

void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.Find("player");
    if(//insert condition)
    {
        player.GetComponent<playerManager>().gender = "man";
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it included a step-by-step breakdown or example code demonstrating how this strategy could be applied to solve OP's problem.